# How do you stub a method to return an array

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, tdd

I have DocumentService class like this:

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Api\StorageServiceInterface;

class DocumentService
{

    private $storageService;

    function __construct(StorageServiceInterface $storageService)
    {
        $this->storageService = $storageService;
    }

    public function createFolder(User $user)
    {
        $folderData = $this->storageService->createFolder(
            '/Users/' . $user->email
        );

        $user->folder = $folderData['folder_id'];
        $user->save();

        return $user->folder;
    }
}
```

Partial implmentation of the `LocalStorageService`.

```
namespace App\Api;

class LocalStorageService implements StorageServiceInterface
{
    public function createFolder($folder)
    {
        ...

        return ['folder_id' => $folder_id, 'folder_path' => $folder_path];
    }
}
```

I'm testing the `DocumentService` class. I'm trying to mock the `createFolder()` method on the `LocalStorageService` which implements `StorageServiceInterface`.

**How do I configure this stub to return the array with PHPUnit?**

I've tried this: (partial code from my test)

```
namespace Tests\Unit\Services;

use App\User;
use App\Api\LocalStorageService;

public function testCreateFolder()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();

    $localStorageService = $this->createMock(LocalStorageService::class);

    $localStorageService->method('createFolder')
            ->willReturn(array('folder_id' => 'random_id', 'folder_path' => ("/Users/" . $user->email)));
}
```

But I'm only getting **random_id**.

Comment: update question include `StorageServiceInterface` as part of the [mcve] used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

Comment: Added the minimal code. Thanks. I did go through the documentation, but could not find how to return array from mocked method.

Comment: You are mocking the wrong thing. mock the abstraction not the implementation.

Comment: Sounds good. I did go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226323/mocking-a-class-vs-mocking-its-interface. I'll mock the interface. Just curious if it is possible to make sure the mocked method returns array in phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

Although it should work with classes as well as interfaces, interfaces should be preferred as this is what client of the interface expects.

This following should work:

```php
public function testCreateFolder()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $folderPath = '/Users/' . $user->email;

    $localStorageService = $this->createMock(StorageServiceInterface::class);

    $localStorageService
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('createFolder')
        ->with($folderPath)
        ->willReturn(
            ['folder_id' => 'random_id', 'folder_path' => $folderPath]
        );


     $documentService = new DocumentService($localStorageService);
     $documentService->createFolder($user);
}
```

By adding the `with()` call you're making sure only if the path is passed it returns the given array.