# Difference between Readonly instance fields and Static readonly fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are the difference between `Readonly instance fields` and `Static readonly fields` ?

> And how can we implement the `Static readonly fields` by [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static vs non-static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924223/static-vs-non-static-class-members). There are other questions on SO that answer your questions: [What are the benefits to marking a field as `readonly` in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c)

Comment: The static one is static; that is the entire difference. And you "implement" it by adding a modifier... so... what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Readonly instance fields and Static Readonly fields is that **Readonly** are evaluated when instance is created and Must have set value by the time constructor exits. whereas, **Static readonly** fields are evaluated when code execution hits class reference (i.e.: new instance is created or static method is executed) and Must have evaluated value by the time static constructor is done