# Error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Collision.gameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let me start by saying that I am a complete beginner, who only got this far by piecing together parts from tutorials and sites like this.

All I am trying to do is make a platform that moves only when stood on.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool isPlayerOn;


[SerializeField]
Transform platform;

[SerializeField]
Transform startTransform;

[SerializeField]
Transform endTransform;

[SerializeField]
float platformSpeed;

Vector3 direction;
Transform destination;


void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other) {

    if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        isPlayerOn = true;
    }

}


void OnCollisionExit (Collision other) {

    if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        isPlayerOn = false;
    }

}

void Start (){
    SetDestination (startTransform);
}



void FixedUpdate(){
    platform.rigidbody.MovePosition (platform.position + direction * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    if (Vector3.Distance (platform.position, destination.position) < platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime) {
        SetDestination (destination == startTransform ? endTransform : startTransform);
    }
}


void SetDestination(Transform dest){
    destination = dest;
    direction = (destination.position -platform.position).normalized;
}

}
```

Now I have no idea if this will even work, I managed to get rid of about 9 other errors but not this one.

Assets/MovingPlatform.cs(31,31): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Collision.gameObject'

Comment: Maybe `other.gameObject.tag` instead `Collision.gameObject.tag`?

Comment: @Snuffleupagus were you ever able to get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing the code to:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other) {

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        isPlayerOn = true;
    }

}
```

instead of:

```
if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
```

The error is telling you that there is no static member called `gameObject` on the `Collision` class. To call non-static members, you need an object reference. In this case, it looks like the object reference should be the `other` instance passed in to this method.

You may also want to do a few searches on static vs. non-static. There are some good answers here:
[Static vs non-static class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924223/static-vs-non-static-class-members)