# 'Object' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to create an event handler and I am getting the error : `'Object' does not contain a definition for ListCountLastH "` and same for `listCountLH`.

Changing `private List` to `public List` makes no difference and I am pretty sure I have to initialise the lists in `protected override void OnStateChange()` but anyway `public /*override*/ void OnStateChange()` makes no difference, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

`public class Incrementer : DivergenceList5m` throws `ListCountLastH` and `listCountLH` inaccessible due to protection level

`DivergenceList5m.ListCountLastH.Add(DivergenceList5m.listCountLH);` throws additionally `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property'Namwspace.Class.ListCountLastH "` and same for `listCountLH` and I just don't know what else to try...

Thank you

```
public class Divergence5min : Strategy
{
   public int listCountLH;
   private List<int> ListCountLastH;
   private List<double> LastHSwDMI;

   protected override void OnStateChange()
   {
      ListCountH            = new List<int>(); 
      LastHSwDMI            = new List<double>();
   }
   ...
   protected override void OnBarUpdate()
   {  
     if (!LHsDmiAdd && b > 1 && HSwDMI[b-1] - HSwDMI[b] > 0.001 && HSwDMI[b-1] - HSwDMI[b-2] > 0.001)
     {
       LastHSwDMI.Add(HSwDMI[b-1]);
       listCountLH = LastHSwDMI.Count;
       ListCountLastH.Add(listCountLH);
      ...
     }
   }
   public class Incrementer
   {
      public EventHandler ItemAdded;

      public void AddItem()
      {

        base.ListCountLastH.Add(base.listCountLH);
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded(this, null);
      }
   }
}
```

Modifying like this with the `private List` still throws the 'inaccessible due to its protection level' error. The subscriber class does not throw any errors, though

```
public class Incrementer : DivergenceList5m
{
    public event EventHandler ItemAdded;            
    public void AddItem()
    {
        var divList = new DivergenceList5m();
        divList.ListCountLastH.Add(divList.listCountLH);
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded(this, null);
    }
}

class AddingItems
{
    public int ItemsCount {get; private set;}

    public void Items (Incrementer incrementer)
    {
        ItemsCount = 0;
        incrementer.ItemAdded += AddItems;

    }
    void AddItems (object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsCount++;               
    }
}
```

Last code version

```
public class Divergence5min : Strategy
{
   public int listCountLH;
   public List<int> ListCountLastH;
   public List<double> LastHSwDMI;
...
public class Incrementer : DivergenceList5m
        {
            public event EventHandler ItemAdded;            

            public void AddItem()
            {
                var divList = new DivergenceList5m();
                divList.ListCountLastH.Add(divList.listCountLH);
                if (ItemAdded != null)
                    ItemAdded(this, null);
            }
        }

        class AddingItems
        {
            public int ItemsCount {get; private set;}

            public void Items (Incrementer inc)
            {
                ItemsCount = 0;
                inc.ItemAdded += AddItems;              
            }
            void AddItems (object source, EventArgs e)
            {
                ItemsCount++;               
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Looks like you are calling `base.listCountLH` in a class which [inherits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) from `object` (i.e. you have not inherited it from anything - `object` is the default type). You need to inherit from `Divergence5min` like this:

   ```
   public class Incrementer: Divergence5min
   ```
2. In order to now call `ListCountLastH` from here, that property should be at least [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) in order to access it from an inherited class:

   ```
   protected List<int> ListCountLastH;
   ```
3. To access [non-static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924223/static-vs-non-static-class-members) members on a class you need to instantiate it first with:

   ```
   var divList = new DivergenceList5m();
   divList.ListCountLastH.Add(divList.listCountLH);
   ```

Comment: Bassie, thank you for the answer, but as per my edit, I still have the protection level error (even with `protected List)`

Comment: @SorinPascu in your edit you mentioned that the list is `private`, was that in error? Please try setting it to `public` and see what happens

Comment: `private` was your fist advice, then I changed it to `protected` and now to `public`, all with no success, I'm afraid

Comment: @SorinPascu Please update your question with the full code you are now running